# GTK: Error while adding some style to text

Tags: python-2.7, gtk, warnings, markup, pygobject

Recently, while doing some experiments and playing with GTK + Python2 (Glade not included) I discovered some interesting behaviour while adding some "style" to my text, which, in fact, is some standard **markup** that usually is accepted by GTK as a valid input, BUT if I try to add the "mnemonic" property to the text itself while using markup too, it will throw a GTK-WARNING saying that something went wrong (Markup wasn't applied) **BUT it was applied indeed!**

Some images to clarify my situation:

---

## Mnemonic: *False* & Markup: True ----> OK

[image: 1.png]

---

## Mnemonic: *True* & Markup: False ----> OK

[image: 2.png]

---

## Mnemonic: *True* & Markup: True ----> GTK-WARNING (But everything's fine...)

[image: 3.png]

[image: 4.png]

Supposed "Problematic" line:

```
Label_1.set_markup_with_mnemonic('<span font_desc="Monospace 64" underline="none"> _Text </span>')
```

I firmly believe that this line shouldn't be a problem, because, as I've explained before, this just happens if I try to add "Mnemonics & Markup" properties at the same time, and nonetheless, it displays and works correctly.

Now, for the real question:

**Is there any possible way to get rid of this useless GTK-WARNING directly from Python (Not needing to use shell features like redirecting to /dev/null, because I'm trying to make this app "shell-proof")**

**Or if there's a way to solve this issue?**

**Or either to workaround this?**

Hints:

- Maybe "_" means something in markup that works like a tag ("`<i>`")?
- GTK Bug?
- Glade suffers from this rare situation too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, it was some kind of weird error inside the **markup** string.

Don't use `<span font_desc=something...`

Instead use `<span font=something...`

This way, GTK won't complain anymore. Maybe this proves that `_` is used for something else in Pango's Markup code?